# connection refused mysql with telnet

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, mysql-replication, telnet

i have 2 machines that can see each other and ping my issue is i want to telnet from slave machine to master machine and this is what i get:

```
slave@slave:~$ telnet 192.168.1.131 3306
Trying 192.168.1.131...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

because im trying to troubleshoot why replication not working this is the result of `show slave status \G`:

```
Last_IO_Error: Error connecting to source 'replication@192.168.1.53:3306'. This was attempt 65/86400, with a delay of 60 seconds between attempts. Message: Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.53:3306' (111)
```

anyway i think if telnet works replication will be ok too.

i disabled firewall in both machine with `sudo ufw disable` and also i didnt find `bind-address` in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` that means it doesnt have any blacklist for get request in master.

could you please give me some tip?

Comment: `Connection refused` indicates that nothing is listening on the intended interface on that port. Possibly mysqld only binds to the loopback interface. Use `ss -tnlp|grep 3306` to check where it is listening.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider i ran it in master and this is result:
LISTEN 0      151        127.0.0.1:3306       0.0.0.0:*          
LISTEN 0      70         127.0.0.1:33060      0.0.0.0:*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mysqld is only listening on the loopback interface. Add the `bind-address` parameter to the `[mysqld]` section and restart mysqld.

```ini
[mysqld]
bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: i added this to /etc/mysql/my.cnf now the result of ss -tnlp|grep 3306 is 
LISTEN 0      151          0.0.0.0:3306       0.0.0.0:*          
LISTEN 0      70         127.0.0.1:33060      0.0.0.0:*
but still same error

Comment: Are you testing the correct host? Your telnet command connects to `192.168.1.131` while the error message mentions `192.168.1.53`.